# Does anyone know why paintEvent is not working?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a code here that would display image that has zoom and pantool function. I added the **paintEvent** fucntion so that I can draw on top of the image while it is on zoom state. Does anyone know how to combine the painEvent function into the current pixmap?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
class PhotoViewer(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    photoClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QPoint)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(PhotoViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self._zoom = 0
        self._empty = True
        self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._photo = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self._scene.addItem(self._photo)
        self.setScene(self._scene)
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(30, 30, 30)))
        self.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)


    def hasPhoto(self):
        return not self._empty

    def fitInView(self, scale=True):
        rect = QtCore.QRectF(self._photo.pixmap().rect())
        if not rect.isNull():
            self.setSceneRect(rect)
            if self.hasPhoto():
                unity = self.transform().mapRect(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, 1, 1))
                self.scale(1 / unity.width(), 1 / unity.height())
                viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
                scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)
                factor = min(viewrect.width() / scenerect.width(),
                             viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            self._zoom = 0

    def setPhoto(self, pixmap=None):
        self._zoom = 0
        if pixmap and not pixmap.isNull():
            self._empty = False
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(pixmap)
        else:
            self._empty = True
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap())
        self.fitInView()

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if self.hasPhoto():
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                factor = 1.25
                self._zoom += 1
            else:
                factor = 0.8
                self._zoom -= 1
            if self._zoom > 0:
                self.scale(factor, factor)
            elif self._zoom == 0:
                self.fitInView()
            else:
                self._zoom = 0

    def toggleDragMode(self):
        if self.dragMode() == QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag:
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
        elif not self._photo.pixmap().isNull():
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self._photo.isUnderMouse():
            self.photoClicked.emit(self.mapToScene(event.pos()).toPoint())
        super(PhotoViewer, self).mousePressEvent(event)


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.viewer = PhotoViewer(self)
        # 'Load image' button
        self.btnLoad = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.btnLoad.setText('Load image')
        self.btnLoad.clicked.connect(self.loadImage)
        # Button to change from drag/pan to getting pixel info
        self.btnPixInfo = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self)
        self.btnPixInfo.setText('Enter pixel info mode')
        self.btnPixInfo.clicked.connect(self.pixInfo)
        self.editPixInfo = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.editPixInfo.setReadOnly(True)
        self.viewer.photoClicked.connect(self.photoClicked)
        # Arrange layout
        VBlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        VBlayout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        HBlayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        HBlayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnLoad)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.btnPixInfo)
        HBlayout.addWidget(self.editPixInfo)
        VBlayout.addLayout(HBlayout)
        
        self.pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("picture.png")
        self.path = QtGui.QPainterPath()

    def loadImage(self):
        filename = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "Open File")
        self.image = filename[0]
        self.pixmap = QPixmap(self.image[0])
        self.viewer.setPhoto(QtGui.QPixmap(self.pixmap))
        self.pixmap = QPixmap(self.image[0])

    def pixInfo(self):
        self.viewer.toggleDragMode()

    def photoClicked(self, pos):
        if self.viewer.dragMode()  == QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.NoDrag:
            self.editPixInfo.setText('%d, %d' % (pos.x(), pos.y()))
    
    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        if self.path.elementCount() == 0:
            self.path.moveTo(e.pos())
        else:
            self.path.lineTo(e.pos())
        self.update()
        super().mousePressEvent(e)

    def paintEvent(self, ev):
        qp = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 5)
        qp.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.pixmap)
        qp.setPen(pen)
        qp.drawPath(self.path)

        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.black)
        qp.setBrush(brush)

        for i in range(self.path.elementCount()):
            e = self.path.elementAt(i)
            qp.drawEllipse(QtCore.QPoint(e.x, e.y), 5, 5)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I think the problem is the self.rect() cause it is different to the pixmap? I am not sure but anyone can help me? Thank you!

Comment: The photo-viewer is a [QGraphicsView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html), so you should use the [Graphics View Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html) to add other graphical elements to the view.

Comment: @ekhumoro, thank you. I already look the Graphics View Framework, and I tried to add mousePressEvent in the photoViewer class, but it is not working, unlike mouseMoveEvent and mouseReleaseEvent. Do you know why mousePressEvent does work? Do you have some examples code that I can refer to? It will be a big help since I am new to this.